# How to add a negative line item or an equivalent of a discount in Stripe new checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have my own shop engine and I use Stripe new checkout for payments, where a customer would be redirected and make payments at checkout.stripe.com.

When there's a discount in an order, I want to be able to simply add a negative line item into an order instead of having to create a discount at Stripe and then apply it to an order. This is because in my shop engine I may apply a discount to shipping, or to a whole order, or to certain products within an order, and it may be difficult to reflect that at Stripe as a discount because discounts at Stripe aren't this flexible. Also I'd have to have my discounts and the ones at Stripe at sync -- more work.

Therefore, I'd simply calculate it and add a negative line, a one with a negative "amount", item on my side.

However, it's not allowed to add a negative line item. What'd be a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that Checkout `line_items` must have a [positive `amount` value](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-unit_amount).

My recommendation would be to instead re-calculate your cart items/total based on any discounts before creating the Checkout session.

Comment: that won't work because where and how would I indicate whether or not the prices include discount(s)? let alone how much of a discount

Comment: If your intention is for the hosted Checkout page to show the applied discounts, then your only current option is to use Stripe coupons/promotional codes with products/prices.

Comment: I've asked how to avoid using them

Comment: Then there's no alternative when using Stripe Checkout I'm afraid. You'd be better suited to build your own [custom checkout with Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&lang=node&client=html&ui=elements).

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to invest time in Stripe Elements just yet, but I found a solution that works for me.

In the Stripe API call where you declare all your products using `lineItems.push()` etc, just check if you have discounts applied and then change the product list to a single product item (e.g. 'Special offer with discounts') and set the quantity to 1 and the `unit_amount` to your discounted total.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I applied the discount percentage to each of the cost of the item that is being sent to the line items.
In the end, you will still get the discount amount that the person will pay